# AutoMapper: Map null source object to decimal

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I need to map an object of type PriceValue to a decimal value and I have the following mapping configured:

```
public class PriceValue
{
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    ...
}

...

Mapper.CreateMap<PriceValue, decimal>()
    .ConvertUsing(src => src.Value);
```

The problem is when `src` is `null` an exception is thrown.

What's the best way to configure the mapping so a `default(decimal)` is returned instead?

Comment: can you not do this ? `.ConvertUsing(src => src == null ? default(decimal) : src.Value);`

Comment: Would using a struct fix the problem? I think @Ric has the better answer though.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing something similar but thought there might be a build-in function that provides a more elegant syntax. Something like the `.NullSubstitute()` but on an object level.

Comment: You could always write it into the setter method.

Comment: I would make this explicit. Because: what value would you expect?

Comment: Can't make changes in `PriceValue`. I just want to default to the default value for the type when the source is null. Would be great if I could write it in C# 6 but can't migrate to 6 yet.

Comment: Have you tried `.ConvertUsing(src => src.Value, opt.Condition(src != null))` ? I'm not in a position to test this myself at the moment.

Comment: @Eris, there is no such overload.

Answer (score 4):

In C# 6 this is pretty straightforward:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PriceValue, decimal>()
    .ConvertUsing(src => src?.Value ?? default(decimal));
```

With ConvertUsing you completely override all mapping configuration, so no other options are available for you.

Comment: Wouldn't that be in C# *6* instead?

Answer (score 0):

We are using a similar system of classes like PriceValue that contain an int, long, etc.  We were able to create a generic mapping against our base class.  Here would be the setup:

```
public class PriceValue : ValueDecimal
{
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Mapping then becomes:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ValueDecimal, decimal>().ConvertUsing(f => f != null ? f.Value : default(decimal));
```

If you use this approach (having a base class) then you avoid having to setup a mapping for every new class you create.

Comment: Yeah, this is the construction we ended up using after all but I still think it is not elegant enough...